# Почему Android Studio не сразу видит обновления?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Использую Android Studio 4.1.1. windows 7. Пишу на Java. Заметил такую особенность работы программы. Меняю что-то в коде, макете или ресурсах. Запускаю программу и вижу, что мои изменения не появились! Сначала приходит мысль, что я где-то ошибся. Начинаю искать ошибку. Не нахожу. Запускаю программу ещё раз и она уже работает как надо. Сейчас к этому уже привык. Чем больше программа, тем чаще это происходит. Чтобы быть уверенным в результате приходится каждый раз запускать программу дважды, потому что я не уверен, что на этот раз все изменения вступили в силу. Это очень не удобно. Подскажите, из-за чего это происходит и как решить эту проблему.

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Вы обновились до Arctic Fox? Ваша проблема была тоже, сейчас исчезла

Comment: Только что установил. Попробую

Comment: как именно "запускаю"?

Comment: Нажимаю Shift-F10 или кнопку Run

Answer (score 0):

Build -> Clean Project
Мне помогло

Clean Project как следует из названия - чистит его, удаляя временные файлы сборки. Бывает полезно при разных глюках, когда вы меняете что-то в коде/ресурсах но не видите изменений при перезапуске, т.к. старая версия файла осталась во временной папке. Также помогает при смене версии либы - в последнем gradle есть баг с дублирующимися зависимостями из-за этого, который лечится как раз очисткой проекта.

Comment: Выше мне посоветовали поставить Arctic Fox. Поставил. Пока полёт нормальный.